# Transfer USD to inr

Tags: united-states, india, tax-professionals

I am a dentist, and I have a patient who is coming from USA for his dental treatment.

He wants to transfer money to my bank account, will it attract taxes?
If so what's the percentage?

Comment: Your patient is paying you for professional services. Why would this payment not count as income for you and thus be subject to income tax (subject to various legally-permitted deductions)?

Comment: Legally permitted deduction? Do I have any?

Comment: @ravisha In some countries (don't know about India), _business_ expenses (e.g. the rent you pay for your office, electrical bill for your office, receptionist's salary, supplies you need to practice dentistry, etc.) can be deducted from the gross income from your practice (all the money you collect from your patients) and what is taxable income to you is the difference.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the funds are being transferred for his treatment, Yes it should be added to your income and taxed at the bracket you fall into. This is same as a person walking into your clinic and paying you cash/cheque/credit card to get treated.